# Dynamically accessing variables in python

Tags: python

There are 9 texts called text1, text2, ... text9. A function is defined as follow.

```
def lexical_diversity(text):
    return len(set(text))/len(text)
```

I want to call the function for all 9 texts with following code. But the outpu is wrong.

```
for i in range(1,10):
    a='text'+str(i)
    print(lexical_diversity(a))
```

My output is

```
0.8
0.8
...
0.8
```

If applying the function to text1, I get following result.

```
>>>lexical_diversity(text1)
   Out[37]:0.07406285585022564
```

So which part goes wrong?

Comment: What does text1 contain?

Comment: `'text'+str(i)`gives `"text1"`, `"text2"`, ... the actual strings. So you get the lexical diversity of `"text1"`, `"text2"`, ... If you have multiple texts you want to access, you probably want to store them in an array, not in separated variables otherwise you cannot loop on them.

Comment: @spectras I see my errors. Thanks. Anyway to fix it?

Comment: @LeiHao> well, I didn't add anything because cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's answer below is the right way to do this. I would suggest you look for `python list tutorial` on your search engine of choice, you'll get a better understanding of how to handle lists of things :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should understand that `a = 'text' + str(i)` does not magically bestow upon `a` the value of whatever is contained inside the variable `text1`. Instead, `a` is assigned to the *string* `"text1"`. The two are *not* the same.

Given the names, you should probably consider storing your `text`s in a `list`:

```
texts = [text1, text2, text3, ...]
```

And now,

```
for a in texts:
    print(lexical_diversity(a))
```

Comment: Given the names I would advocate an array. `texts[i]` sounds better than `texts["text"+str(i)]`.

Comment: What I mean is given his variable names, I believe there is no semantic content in his `text1`, `text2`, .... He merely have texts, and added a number to his variables names.

Comment: I see my errors. Is there a way to create this list quickly, instead of typing text1, text2,...? A for-loop or something?

Comment: @LeiHao Yes. There's a quick and dirty solution. It involves manipulating globals. Do this: `texts = [globals()['text' + str(i)] for i in range(1, 10)]` You must wonder... why not use globals directly? Well, it's major code smell.

Comment: @akp That just puts strings in there, not the actual variable content.

Comment: @LeiHao [vars()['text'+str(j)] for j in range(1,10)]

Comment: @LucasB Apparently OP is lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Python3

```
def lexical_diversity(text):
    return len(set(text))/len(text)
lista = []
for i in range(1,10):
    lista.append("text%d" % i) 
for resVal in lista:
    print(resVal) 
    print(lexical_diversity(resVal))
```